# File name mismatch android

Tags: android, file, audio-recording

I am recording some audio from mic and then uploading that to the server.

But there is one problem while uploading. The file name mismatches.

I am creating the filename using timestamp and when I pass that filename to the upload function file name varies by 2 seconds. For example, if my file name is `File_1234` then it passing as `File_1236`. File is saved as `File_1234` on storage, but upload function is finding `File_1236`

*Function to create file*:

```
private File makeOutputFile () {
    mPath1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    mFileName1 = "/Call" + "_" + getTimeStamp() + ".3gp";
    mFileStorageDirectory1 = new File(mPath1 + "/SalesLineCallRecordings");
    if (!mFileStorageDirectory1.exists()) {
        if (!mFileStorageDirectory1.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    mFile1 = new File(mFileStorageDirectory1.getPath() + mFileName1);
    mFilePath1 = mFile1.getAbsolutePath();

    return mFile1;
}
```

*Getting timestamp:*

```
public static String getTimeStamp() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

*Upload function:*

```
private void uploadActivity(boolean isConnected) {
    if (isConnected) {
        Log.e("", "File path" + mFilePath1);
        //new UploadAsync().execute(mFilePath);
        type1 = "yes";
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), UploadService.class);
        intent.putExtra("type", type1);
        intent.putExtra("audioFile", mFilePath1);
        startService(intent);
    } 
    else {
        audio.setAudioRecording(mFilePath1);
        audioDbHelper.addAudio(audio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you find both `File_1234` and `File_1236` on storage or just `File_1234`?

Comment: Only file_1234 is available

Comment: How many times are you calling `makeOutputFile()` method?

Comment: Only once before the start of recording

Comment: You're doing something else with `mFilePath1`? In this case post that portion of code. Post also `setAudioRecording()` method, please